# Can't figure out how to append JSON into a single parent object

Tags: python, json

I'm having an issue which I can't figure out the solution of.  I'm trying to build a JSON object.  I'm working with some VMware API and I'm building a JSON object for usernames and nesting VM information inside.  I'm having trouble building the nested objects.  See below and I'll explain further.  Note, annotation is used as a tag to identify the owner of the virtual machine.

```
owner_logged_in = "johndoe"
service_instance = connect.SmartConnectNoSSL(host='10.0.0.202', user='', pwd='')
atexit.register(connect.Disconnect, service_instance)
content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()
container = content.rootFolder  # starting point to look into
viewType = [vim.VirtualMachine]  # object types to look for
recursive = True  # whether we should look into it recursively
containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(container, viewType, recursive)
children = containerView.view

virtual_machines = []
vm_username = {}
vm_container = {}
for child in children:
    summary = child.summary
    annotation = summary.config.annotation
    if owner_logged_in == annotation:
        children = []
        children.append({'ip': summary.guest.ipAddress,'power': summary.runtime.powerState})
        vm_container['name'] = summary.config.name
        vm_username[owner_logged_in] = vm_container
        vm_container['properties'] = children
        jsonvalues = json.dumps(vm_username)
        #debug#
        print(jsonvalues)
        #debug#
```

The returned results are as follows:

```
 {"johndoe": {"name": "centos01", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.201", "power": "poweredOn"}]}}
 {"johndoe": {"name": "dc01", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.200", "power": "poweredOn"}]}}
```

I need to somehow combine these two into 1 object that I can store in a value which then I'm using a DJANGO web app iterate through the value to build a table using some javascript (tabullar.js).  I can handle that part but what I'm struggling with is coming up with a way to make 1 object.  A user might have more than one virtual machines and I need the properties of each but make the 'johndoe' be the parent.

Essentially I need it formatted to look like this to properly convert it to a table using the tabular.js.

```
{  
  "johndoe":[  
     {  
        "name":"centos01",
        "properties":[  
           {  
              "ip":"10.0.0.201",
              "power":"poweredOn"
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"dc01",
        "properties":[  
           {  
              "ip":"10.0.0.200",
              "power":"poweredOn"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Note that generally, we ask for questions to have a **minimal** reproducer, the *shortest possible code* that lets someone else reproduce a specific problem when run without additions, modifications, or setup. If you could reproduce the confusion at the core of your question in four lines -- two defining dicts, one defining a list, one trying to merge the dicts into a single list item, f/e -- then you *should* to do so, to better comply with the site's [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try follwing:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

virtual_machines = []
vm_username = defaultdict(list)
vm_container = defaultdict(list)
for child in children:
    summary = child.summary
    annotation = summary.config.annotation
    if owner_logged_in == annotation:
        children = []
        children.append({'ip': summary.guest.ipAddress,'power': summary.runtime.powerState})
        vm_container['name'] = summary.config.name
        vm_username[owner_logged_in].append(vm_container)
        vm_container['properties'] = children

jsonvalues = json.dumps(vm_username, indent=4)
#debug#
print(jsonvalues)
#debug#
```

Comment: I see what you're doing but i'm getting this - couldnt make sense as to why it was erroring out.      vm_username[owner_logged_in].append(vm_container)
KeyError: 'johndoe'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing if you can just append it to a list the following solution should work.

```
import json
d_list=[
{"johndoe": {"name": "centos01", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.201", "power": "poweredOn"}]}},
{"johndoe": {"name": "dc01", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.200", "power": "poweredOn"}]}},
{"janedoe": {"name": "centos02", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.201", "power": "poweredOn"}]}},
{"janedoe": {"name": "dc02", "properties": [{"ip": "10.0.0.200", "power": "poweredOn"}]}}
]
d_new={name:[v for x in d_list for k,v in x.items() if k ==name] for name in set(list(y)[0] for y in d_list)}
# for printing output properly
print(json.dumps(d_new,indent=4))
```

Output

```
{
    "johndoe": [
        {
            "name": "centos01",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "ip": "10.0.0.201",
                    "power": "poweredOn"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dc01",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "ip": "10.0.0.200",
                    "power": "poweredOn"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "janedoe": [
        {
            "name": "centos02",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "ip": "10.0.0.201",
                    "power": "poweredOn"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dc02",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "ip": "10.0.0.200",
                    "power": "poweredOn"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```